# remove spaces from matched pattern in regex js

Tags: javascript, regex

I am removing classes from a HTML element according to some conditions. This is my regex pattern:

```
elem.className = elem.className.replace(/shake|progress|done/g, '');
```

but this pattern has a problem that if somebody adds another class say `shaker`, that will also be removed. so I changed the pattern to:

```
elem.className = elem.className.replace(/(^|\s)shake(\s|$)|(^|\s)progress(\s|$)|(^|\s)done(\s|$)/g, '');
```

now it removes only if the whole word matches. but now it removes the spaces around the word. I am not sure how to fix this issue. please help me with this.

Comment: This is not a job for regex. Interact with [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) instead.

Comment: Can you give an accurate example of before and after, meaning string before and after regex applied

Comment: Derek has the right answer; but the technique to match whole words only with regexes might be worth mentioning anyway: Take a look at [word boundary anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html).

Comment: For your regex question, use word boundaries: `/\b(?:shake|progress|done)\b/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a job for regex. Interact with [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) instead.

```
elem.classList.remove("shake", "progress", "done"); // removes all 3 class values
```

Comment: Thanks, that will work. But, maybe in some other case where I need to match the whole word. what should be the regex pattern.

Answer (score 0):

classList.remove is the best way.

This answers your question:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="tt" class="eins zwei drei meins">ABC</div>
</body>
  <script>
    tt.className=tt.className.replace(/\beins|zwei|drei/g, '');
  </script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with others that `classList` is the way to go here, however you could accomplish this if you want to match whole words. Split `className` on space and filter any items that are in your list of classes to remove:

```
const classes = elem.className.split(' ');
const remove = ['shake', 'progress', 'done'];

elem.className = classes.filter(cls => !remove.includes(cls)).join(' ');
```